# How to run script every time page loads

Tags: javascript, console, devtools

How do I run my scripts every time page loads instead of pasting them to the console after refreshing/loading page?

Comment: If you press the up arrow it remembers the last script you ran in the console.  At least in Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: If you mean "permanently add this script to the web page that was in the browser at the time" the answer is: **No, no way to do that**

Comment: @RandyCasburn thank you for the answer.

Comment: What you appear to be wanting to achieve (have a script of your own run every time a specific page is loaded) can be done by creating a userscript (or less commonly, a browser extension). If you are going to use userscripts, then you will want to install a userscript manager. The most commonly used one is Tampermonkey. You will want to Google "userscript" and "userscript manager".

Comment: However, your question is unclear and reads like an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). Please describe in more detail what it is you are attempting to achieve, not how you're attempting to achieve it. For instance, "I want to have a script that runs whenever a specific page is loaded", not "I want to enter something into Devtools that runs forever."

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's no way to keep a script from developer tools to be running all the time. All you do in the developer tools console, is shown **only** on your side. It does not affect the original website. Logically, if you could change some website and implement your own scripts, only by using the developer tools console, that would make it that every website could be **breached** / **hacked** as you please. So yea, short and simple answer, **there's no way to keep a script / code you typed in the developer tools console, to run even after you close the window.**

Comment: This describes a very limited view of what is possible. While it's true that code entered into the DevTools console *for the page* stops running when the page is reloaded, there are certainly ways to have your own code run on a page every time you load it. This is specifically what userscripts do. For example, I have about 20 different scripts, that were not supplied in-page, which were automatically loaded and run when this Stack Exchange page was opened.

Comment: Hmm okay, but then again, do those userscripts that you mention, change something in the website, or the changes they make can only be seen by you ? Also, do those userscripts work something like extensions or..? It wasn't really clear what he wants to achieve though :)

Comment: Yes, the userscripts change things in the page which are visible to me, that's basically the point of using them. Userscripts are usually maintained in the browser by a userscript manager extension. Userscripts have some expanded capabilities beyond what page-scripts can do (there's an API), but not as much capability as extensions. There's some more information in the [tag:userscripts] [tag info](//stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info). [Stack Aps](//stackapps.com/) has a large quantity of userscripts intended for use on Stack Exchange, but there are *lots more* that aren't listed there.

Comment: I agree that the OP's question isn't clear (I've voted to close as unclear). In such cases, it's usually better to post a comment asking for clarification (and flag/vote for closure as unclear, unless it's a relatively minor issue), rather than an answer.